# Redirect not updating history with react-router-dom in version 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom`:

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';`


  `<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/application" component={Application} />
      </App>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);`

I am using `<Redirect />` to redirect but only when a form is in valid state:

`</div>
    {submitSucceeded && <Redirect to={nextLink} />}`

But when I go to the next link and click back it goes back to the route of the site, i.e. the history is not being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `withRouter`, here is a [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md) which explains it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct approach is to use the property push set to true. As following:

`{submitSucceeded && <Redirect to={nextLink} push={true} />}`

You can see more info on the documentation page:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/push-bool